# Yii2 Pretty URL params

Tags: yii2

I have set pretty URL for yii2 advanced
at config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager', 
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
            ],
        ],
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

some controller

```
$searchModel = new UserSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

but query filter from gridView $searchModel still dirty, can I pretty params like some/action?name=jack&shift_id=1 without UserSearch[name]=jack ?

```
some/action?UserSearch%5Bname%5D=jack&UserSearch%5Bshift_id%5D=1&UserSearch%5Bmanager_id%5D=176
```

Comment: Please show us your `view` contents.

Comment: url params from filter gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override [`formName()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#formName()-detail) in your search model, to return empty string:

```
public function formName() {
    return '';
}
```

Comment: thanks, working..
is any effect if I override formName() in search model with relation table?